# Deploy Qt application on MAC with Qt framework

Tags: macos, qt

I developed one Qt application in Mac using Qt creator,Its working fine on my development machine.Then I copied the project output from my build directory to a new machine without Qt framework,but its not working in that machine, Do I need to install any frame work for running Qt application in Mac. How I can include qt framework in my application when deploying the project output?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't have SSCCE; doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved; and it's asking us to asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource.

Comment: I solved it by using the "macdeployqt" tool
http://blog.inventic.eu/2012/08/how-to-deploy-qt-application-on-macos-part-ii/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to have read [Developing Qt Applications for Mac OS X](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/developing-on-mac.html).

Answer (score 0):

See [Qt for macOS - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html) specifically, and [Qt for macOS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx.html) generally.

Answer (score -2):

The binary will be in your Debug or Release folder and it will be as .app

(.app extension may be hidden )

make sure you copy that and it should work fine as the binary has all its dependencies packed together