# qt / creator: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dyld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deploy Qt application on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411677/deploy-qt-application-on-mac)

I've compiled a release version of my app through qt creator and it runs just fine on my macbook pro (10.8). However, trying to run this same application on my work computer (also 10.8) results in the following runtime error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/Me/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Dropbox/Me/Project/Project.app/Contents/MacOS/Project
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout
```

From what I've read, it sounds like I may need to include the entire Qt framework into my bundle? Is there a way to specify this behavior in the .pro, or some command line compilation flag I need to include?

Comment: This is not compilation but deployment, which qmake doesn't handle (see linked question above)

Comment: I did come across that question, however the link provided in the answer is no longer available.

Comment: Fixed. Also in case using cmake is an option: http://mikemcquaid.com/2012/01/04/deploying-qt-applications-with-deployqt4/